# Is there a way to do a true sql type merge of 2 dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

For starter I'll admit that I'm quite new to dataframes/databricks having worked with them for only a few months.

I have two dataframes read from parquet files (full format). In reviewing the documentation it appears that what in pandas is called merge is in fact only a join.

in SQL I would write this step as:

```
 ml_RETURNS_U = sqlContext.sql("""
  MERGE INTO U2 as target
    USING U as source
    ON (
        target.ITEMNUMBER = source.ITEMNUMBER
        and target.PRODUCTCOLORID = source.PRODUCTCOLORID
        and target.WEEK_ID = source.WEEK_ID
        )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET target.RETURNSALESQUANTITY = target.RETURNSALESQUANTITY + source.QTY_DELIVERED
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (ITEMNUMBER, PRODUCTCOLORID, WEEK_ID, RETURNSALESQUANTITY)
      VALUES (source.ITEMNUMBER, source.PRODUCTCOLORID, source.WEEK_ID, source.QTY_DELIVERED)
""")
```

When I run this command I get the following error: u'MERGE destination only supports Delta sources.\n;'

So I have two questions: Is there a way I can preform this operation using pandas or pySpark?

if not, how can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your tables using DELTA and perform this operation

see: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/index.html

So you can do a upsert using merge like this: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#write-to-a-table

Comment: I don't create the tables. The data is provided from another source as  full format parquet files. I haven't seen a way to convert the full format to a delta format, Is there some optional parameters for the toPandas() method that does this?

Comment: I think you have to insert all data in the target table again. The only way to do updates is using DELTA tables, but if the data is from another source you can not do that.

Comment: Do you know if this holds true for ANY attempt to use sqlContext.sql or only with respect to using a merge?

Comment: Actually if you are using parquet files or hive tables you can not perform updates, so you can only append or overwrite data.

Comment: Thanks for your insight